# Post data flutter app to postgresql db php

Tags: php, postgresql, flutter, insert

I'm failing storing data from my app to my Postgres db and as i don't have any error on my debbuger and i'm struggling to determin if the pb comes from  my app or from php file.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   //....
    getgpscoordinates().then((coord) => checkUser(coord));
   //...}

      Future<List>getgpscoordinates() async{
    final _locdata = await Location().getLocation();
    List<double> _gps= [_locdata.latitude,_locdata.longitude];
    return Future.value(_gps);
   }
  
  // send position 
  Future<dynamic>checkUser(coord) async{
    const String userurl="URLofmyserver/input_db.php";
    final _res = await http.post(userurl, body:{
      "gps":coord.toString(),
    });
    print('transmission en cours');
    return Future.value(_res);
  }
```

And my php insert file look like this :
[It have been edited ] :

```
 <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

include '******/db_connection.php';

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$gps = $_POST['gps'];

$conn = OpenCon();

$stmt->bindValue(':gps', $gps);
$stmt->bindValue(':userappip', $ip);

$sql = "INSERT INTO temporary.usercodb (userappip, gps) VALUES (:userappip, :gps)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);

try{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $stmt->execute();
}catch(\PDOException $e){
    $pdo->rollback();
    echo $e->getMessage();

}


CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

EDIT : I've tried to send th GPS variable throught HTML forms and i get an error on the bindvalue gps (variable is null)

Comment: I don't use PHP so I may be missing something, but I don't see anything in above that commits the transaction.

Comment: it's the first time i trie to work with Future but i call the the first future in the builder :
//  getgpscoordinates().then((coord) => checkUser(coord));
(if i put a print(coord) in my checkUser it prints the coordinates so i guess thats works)

Comment: Pretty sure Future has nothing to do with this. I was referring to your PHP database code. I don't see anything there that issues a `commit` for the `INSERT` transaction. Without a `commit` the data will not persist in the database.

Comment: Oh ok ! I never see the use of commit in php insert files.

Comment: Well something has to `commit` the transaction. Sometimes that is done automatically. It's just that the problem you describe fits with no `commit` being issued. It would be helpful to know what PHP driver you are using and what `OpenCon` and CloseCon actually do?

Comment: I'm using PDO, and Opencon and Closecon are functions to open  /close a connection to db .

Comment: Yes, I figured that but what are the steps being taken inside the functions? For information on `PDO` and transaction see [Transactions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php).

Comment: (thks for your help btw) I can't post more code but the logic is :
to connect :

$conn = new \PDO($dns, $user, $password) or die("Connection failed: %s\n".$conn -> error);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
return $conn;

and to close : 

$conn = null;